# Shoulda and RSpec's before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, shoulda, matcher

I try to set a instance variable in a subject before testing validity of model fields. I need to set this variable, because validation is conditional (it is used only for some type of users). So I have something like this:

```
  context "as a user" do

    before(:each) do
      subject = Organization.new
      subject.editor = "user"
    end

    it { subject.should validate_presence_of :name }

  end
```

But it doesn't work as expected:

```
 Failure/Error: it { subject.should validate_presence_of :description }
 RuntimeError:
   Organization#editor attr is not set
```

What did i miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subject` in your before block is a local variable.  It looks like you meant to use [an explicit subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/subject/explicit-subject#subject-in-a-nested-group):

```
context "as a user" do
  subject { Organization.new }

  before(:each) do
    subject.editor = "user"
  end

  # usually, you don't explicitly name the subject in an `it` like this
  it { should validate_presence_of :name }

end
```